# Le CORS Preflight (OPTIONS)'s Hell

Tags: cors, unauthorized, preflight

**Le Problem:**

I am trying to load a page (securePage.html), that is protected with **basic authentication**, via a **cross-domain** ajax request (CORS).

Basic authentication (Custom-header) + CORS = preflight OPTIONS-Request!

Although credentials are give to the actual request, preflight request doesn't send them!

Response: 401 Unauthorized!

[Snapshot of the 401 Unauthorized error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd2IC.png)

**Le Environment:**

Server: IIS 8.5 hosts my securePage.html. This is my web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4444" />
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST" />
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        // **Authorization rules: only Bob is allowed to view the page, everyone is allowed to send an OPTIONS request.**
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*" verbs="OPTIONS" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="Bob" />
            </authorization>
        </security>        
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

From my local PC (http://localhost:4444) I send the ajax request.

```js
function load(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://[MY_DOMAIN]/secureContent/securePage.html",    
        contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", /* Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.*/
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },                                  
        headers:{
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('Bob:[MY_PASSWORD]') /*Setting custom headers to XHR triggers a preflight request*/
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success');
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('error');
            alert(jqXhr.responseText);
        },

    });
}
```

**Le Question:**

Apparently the authorization rule  doesn't do anything! Why?
I tried:

```
- setting a request filtering (allow OPTIONS);
- giving read access to OPTINOSVerbHanlder;
```

With no success!

Is there any solution to this problem? Did I miss something here?

**Le Solution:**

```js
//TODO...
```

Comment: Got the same problem under Apache2. I finally changed the architecture of my project to avoid that. If I'm not wrong, the solution you have to do in order to allow "OPTIONS", but when a call to OPTIONS is made you have to disable de Basic Authentication: jquery won't send the authentication header to OPTIONS request.

Comment: I still don't get how you got the problem solved! I konw that jquery doen't send the "Authorization" header with the preflight request. But I expected that there is a possibility to tell the server to accept anonymous OPTIONS request. Why does the server refuse the anonymous OPTIONS request, although it is considered a safe request!?